# Who was the murderer? 550971051

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, mystery

The florist has just been murdered, and you, a freelance detective called on to the case by the police, arrive at the crime scene. Three suspects are present in the flower shop: the florist's assistant, the boss of the oil shop next door, and a person who was caught running away from the crime scene shortly after the victim's scream was heard.

On the floor is a blood-stricken ripped piece of paper with the numbers 550971051 in the florist's handwriting.

Who was the murderer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is:

> The boss of the oil shop next door.

Why?

> 550971051 flipped upside down and reversed looks like
>  ISOILGOSS $\rightarrow$ I sell gas
>
>  I've heard this puzzle somwhere before, can't remember where, I'm quite sure this is the answer though

Comment: Your answer and method is correct, but 550971051 upside-down being interpreted as 'I sell gas' is a bit vague. Anyways, I'm going to mark your answer as correct because you have both the answer and the process right

Comment: Thanks! I think I heard this riddle with the murderer being a gas seller instead of oil boss (both meaning similar), so I just wrote what I remember, not realizing that ISOIL6OSS can have 6 $\rightarrow$ b instead of G

Comment: Rolled Back Edit -- Edit fundamentally changes the answer as given.  Also, correct interpretation appears in @valuable_asset 's answer.

Answer (score 11):

Should be

> the oil guy

because

> 550971051 inverted is IS OIL BOSS (15 01L b055)

Comment: Good job on the answer, but the correct way is to read the number upside down. You can try that, I guess :)

Comment: But the answer is derived from reading the number upside down already.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. The world is unfair sometimes. @Non-Puzzler